# Is it possible to define a part of a geometry column as the Primary Key in a PostGIS database?

Tags: postgis

Is it possible to define a part of a geometry column as the Primary Key in a PostGIS database?

For example, when I want to store 3D points in a database, using the x/y coordinate as the primary key.

Comment: I don't think it's good practice to use coordinates in the primary key. What if they change?

Comment: I'm agree with underdark. But nevertheless what is your exact issue? You can't extract coordinates and fill an appropriate column? Or you have troubles with a trigger creation?

Comment: The coordinates won't change, because they represent a given grid. I don't want, that a point is saved twice in the database/grid.
So I want to describe, that only one point with the coordinates (x_p,y_p,z_p) can have the coordinates (x_p,y_p).

Comment: You could try with a trigger to validate your constraints on INSERT and UPDATE (with ST_Equals) and perhaps a simple sequence for your PrimaryKey

Answer (score 2):

No. Well not with a gist index.  I think in pre 1.5 you could with a btree (but that would only work for points), but I wouldn't recommend it even if you can.

You might want to look at exclusion constraints.  It will be somewhat lossy because the bbox is a bit fatter to hold the point, but might be good enough for you needs.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html  (see way at the bottom of the page).  Alternatively you can do a unique key index on ST_X(geom), ST_Y(geom)

The benefit of that is you can control the rounding precision, like

```
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidx_tbl_geomxy  ON tbl 
     USING btree (CAST(ST_X(geom) AS numeric(16,5)), CAST(ST_Y(geom) As numeric(16,5) ));
```